# Windows Server 2019 erroneously changing the subnet on NIC1 to /24 after each reboot, but it should be /22

Tags: networking, subnet, windows-server-2019

Every time I reboot this Windows Server 2019 VM, Windows changes the subnet from 255.255.252.0 to 255.255.255.0 which is incorrect. The subnet must be /22 (255.255.252.0) for traffic to pass.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

I found this Hotfix, but it's only for Server 2012 so I cannot install it:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/subnet-mask-changes-to-an-incorrect-value-and-the-server-goes-offline-in-directaccess-in-windows-server-2012-3ac5d49f-4702-b93d-d5a4-980c38f89a63

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the E1000E virtual NIC ("Intel Pro 1000 MT") with a VMXNET 3 virtual NIC in vSphere resolved the issue.